# Create a multidimensional array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am trying to create an array like this in a loop:

```
$dataPoints = array(
    array('x' => 4321, 'y' => 2364),
    array('x' => 3452, 'y' => 4566),
    array('x' => 1245, 'y' => 3452),
    array('x' => 700, 'y' => 900), 
    array('x' => 900, 'y' => 700));
```

with this code

```
$dataPoints = array();    
$brands = array("COCACOLA","DellChannel","ebayfans","google",
    "microsoft","nikeplus","amazon"); 
foreach ($brands as $value) {
    $resp = GetTwitter($value);
    $dataPoints = array(
        "x"=>$resp['friends_count'],
        "y"=>$resp['statuses_count']);
}
```

but when loop completes my array looks like this:

```
Array ( [x] => 24 [y] => 819 )
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because you're re-assigning `$dataPoints` as a new array on each loop.

Change it to:

```
$dataPoints[] = array("x"=>$resp['friends_count'],"y"=>$resp ['statuses_count']);
```

This will append a new array to the end of `$dataPoints`

Answer (score 1):

use `array_merge($array1,$array2)` make it simple use two array one for use in iteration and another for storing the final result. checkout the code.

```
$dataPoints = array();  
$dataPoint = array();  

$brands = array(
    "COCACOLA","DellChannel","ebayfans","google","microsoft","nikeplus","amazon"); 
foreach($brands as $value){
    $resp = GetTwitter($value);
    $dataPoint = array("x"=>$resp['friends_count'],"y"=>$resp ['statuses_count']);
    $dataPoints = array_merge($dataPoints,$dataPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration you're overwriting $dataPoints variable, but you should add new elements to array...

`$dataPoints[] = array("x"=>$resp['friends_count'],"y"=>$resp ['statuses_count']);`