# Create a multidimensional array based on number of values

Tags: php, loops, foreach

i have an array that i get from a form with alot of fields, i need to order those fields under an array and that array under the ''main'' array. Ill post what i have, and what i need to get.
**WHAT I HAVE:**

```
Array
(
    [perfil_area1] => Array
    (
        [0] => a2
        [1] => a3
    )

    [perfil_years] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 4
    )

    [perfil_function] => Array
    (
        [0] => f1
        [1] => f4
    )

    [perfil_obs] => Array
    (
        [0] => teste1
        [1] => teste2
    )

    [perfil_company] => Array
    (
        [0] => emp1
        [1] => emp2
    )
)
```

This is what i need to be so i can turn it into a query:
**What i need**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    (
        [perfil_area1] => a2
        [perfil_years] =>  2
        [perfil_function] =>  f1
        [perfil_obs] =>  teste1
        [perfil_company] =>  emp1
    )
    [1] =>
    (
        [perfil_area1] => emp2
        [perfil_years] =>  2
        [perfil_function] =>  f4
        [perfil_obs] =>  4
        [perfil_company] =>  a3
    )
)
```

i have tried with 2 foreach but i didnt manage to get it done. I have read [Create a multidimensional array in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497149/create-a-multidimensional-array-in-a-loop/4497166) , [how to create multidimensional array using a foreach loop in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250602/how-to-create-multidimensional-array-using-a-foreach-loop-in-php) , [create multidimensional array using a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135685/create-multidimensional-array-using-a-foreach-loop) , [Converting an array from one to multi-dimensional based on parent ID values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767961/converting-an-array-from-one-to-multi-dimensional-based-on-parent-id-values) and some more but i still cant do it. Any tips on how to create it?

Comment: Have you read how to "transpose" an array?

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/62612089/2943403 (no upvotes on that duplicate).

Comment: Save yourself a lot of hassle and modify your form to suit your process.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799565/2943403

Comment: i can modify it but will take me longer because it has fields added dynamically and i will have to change the js behind it. This way i can just convert the arrays to one array. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop over the input array and build the new array

```
$new = [];
foreach ($in as $key=>$arr) {
    $new[0][$key] = $arr[0];
    $new[1][$key] = $arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$result = [];

for ($i=0; $i<count(reset($array)); $i++) {
    $result[] = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_column($array, $i));
}
```

Please read the manual for more details about [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).